# ellipses not working with actionRenderer in Ag Grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have ag grid in angular project.
This grid has column which is of type ActionCellRendererComponent.

Ellipses working fine for normal column data but not working for ActionCellRendererComponent type column.

```
{
    headerName: "Test",
    field: "test",
    tooltipField: "test",
    width: 120,//SN02
    cellRendererFramework: ActionCellRendererComponent,
    cellRendererParams: {
      class: "button-transparent-background btn-link",
      action: function (arg) {
```

Anybody have any idea